# How to interpret the derivative of a quantum mechanical operator, and what makes sure that the usual differentiation rules are appliable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation

For a function $f(x)$ we can think at its derivative with respect to $x$, $f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}|_{x}$ as a quantitative measure of how the **value** of $f$ changes increasing $x$ by an infinitesimal quantity. When it comes to QM operators, I often see that they are differentiated, and the usual differentiation rules are applied. As an example, for the time evolution operator, $U(t)=e^{-iHt}$:

$$\frac{dU}{dt}=-iHU(t)$$

First of all, I don't understand the concept of derivative of an operator. I usually find explanations like:

> The derivative of an operator expresses how it changes with respect to a variable it depends on

My problem with this kind of explanation is that it's not actually saying what a derivative of operator is. Is it still an operator? How is it representable? For functions I can measure how their value changes when changing the value of a variable, but with operators?
The only thing that I found is a formal definition:
$$\frac{dU(t)}{dt}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{U(t+h)-U(t)}{h}$$
were the difference between the two operators is well defined so it makes sense to me.

From this, however, the second part of my question comes: how can I be sure that I can use the same differentiation rules that are used for functions? In the example above, the time evolution operator, we're applying the differentiation rule for the exponential and the composite function, treating $H$ as a scalar quantity; $H$ is an operator, though, and I don't really know how to treat it...

EDIT:
Also in light of the comment that I got below by @Matteo, here's a further example.

Let's start again with the time evolution operator. An operator valued function can be expressed (or defined) as a power expansion:
$$U(t)=e^{-iHt}=\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}{\left[\frac{1}{n!}\left(-iHt\right)^n\right]}=\mathbb{1}-iHt-\frac{1}{2}H^2t^2+\frac{1}{6}H^3t^3...$$
If I want to take the derivative with respect to $t$, since the matrix $U(t)$ is a simple sum of matrices, I can write:
$$\frac{dU(t)}{dt}=\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}{\left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\left(-iHt\right)^n\right)\right]}$$
so when it comes to the first order we can write the $ij$ element of the matrix $(Ht)$ as $h_{ij}t$, so taking the derivative of $\left(-iHt\right)$ as a matrix whose elements are the derivative of the elements of $\left(-iHt\right)$, the usual rule $(f\cdot g)'=f\cdot g' + f'\cdot g$ is still valid, so:
$$\frac{d\left(-iHt\right)}{dt}=-i\left(H+t\frac{dH}{dt}\right)$$
If we go to the second order, we already have to evaluate, at some point, the derivative of $H^2$. Here I already get confused, because nothing tells me what kind of product I have to use. So, can I say that $$\frac{dH^2}{dt}=2H\frac{dH}{dt}$$
? And already I had to assume the order of the product between these two matrices (while this problem simply does not exist with functions). Moreover, here going to the derivative of the single elements of the matrix, which in this case is $H^2$, doesn't looks like preserving the rules of differentiation. Indeed:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(H^2\right)_{ij}=\sum_k{\left[\frac{dH_{ik}}{dt}H_{kj}+H_{ik}\frac{dH_{kj}}{dt} \right] }$$
while
$$\left(2H\frac{dH}{dt}\right)_{ij}=2\sum_k{\left[H_{ik}\left(\frac{dH}{dt}\right)_{kj}\right]}=2\sum_k{\left[H_{ik}\frac{dH_{kj}}{dt}\right]}$$
(assuming the order of the product is correct). In this case, the two formulas are different, in general.
So here there are two problems:

1. The order of the product is not defined (maybe it can be proved that it doesn't matter?)
2. Assuming an order for the product, still the usual derivation rule doesn't seem to hold in general.

Comment: One thing that could convince you is that operators can be matrices when the Hilbert space is finte-dimensional. The entries of this matrix depend on some parameter $t$ and you can think of the derivative as a matrix whose entries are the derivatives of the corresponding entries of the original matrix. So all of the standard rules of calculus apply

Comment: Hi @Matteo, thank you! I actually read that somewhere and it's quite reassuring, but:
1. The Hilbert space often is not finite-dimensional
2. The rules apply to the single elements of the matrix, but then the matrix itself is used to compose operators through function. E.g. the time evolution op. is composed as the exponential function of the hamiltonian operator; how is this going to reflect to the derivative of the time evolution operator, starting from the hamiltonian?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 7 relevant topologies in the space of operators in Quantum Theories.

Your issue relies on the so-called **strong topology**. According to that (seminormed) topology
$$U_t \to U\quad t\to t_0  \quad \mbox{strongly}$$
for a family of operators $\{U_t\}_{t\in I}$ on a common domain $D$ if
$$\forall \psi\in D:\quad U_t \psi \to U\psi\:, \quad t\to t_0\:.$$
The **weak topology** is another important topology (in QFT more important than the former).
$$U_t \to U\quad t\to t_0\quad \mbox{weakly}$$
for a family of operators $\{U_t\}_{t\in I}$ on a common domain $D$ if
$$\forall \psi, \phi\in D:\quad \langle \phi|U_t \psi\rangle  \to \langle \phi | U\psi\rangle \:, \quad t\to t_0\:.$$

In particular, the strong topology relevant theorem is the **Stone theorem** that I state in a more extended version.

**STONE's THEOREM** *Let $\{U_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ a family of unitary operators on the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$. Suppose that the family is a one-parameter group in $t$:
$$U_{t}U_{s}=U_{t+s}\:, \quad U_0=I\:.$$
The following facts are equivalent.*

1. *$U_t$ is strongly contiunous in $t=0$.*
2. *$U_t$ is strongly continuous in $t=t_0\in \mathbb{R}$.*
3. *$U_t = e^{it A}$ for some selfadjoint operator $A: D(A) \to {\cal H}$, where the exponential is defined by spectral calculus (i.e. for a Borel map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$
   $$f(t) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\lambda) dP^{(A)}(\lambda)$$
   where $P^{(A)}$ is the spectral measure (PVM) of $A$.)*

*The operator $A$ in 3 is unique and it is completely determined by the formula
$$A\psi = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{it} (U_t\psi - \psi)$$
where $\psi \in D(A)\subset {\cal H}$ which is precisely the dense subspace where the limit exists.*

It is important to stress that 1. and 2 are equivalent to

5. $U_t$ is weakly continuous at $t=0$, i.e. $\langle \psi| U_t \phi\rangle \to \langle \psi|\phi\rangle$, as $t\to 0$, for every pair $\psi,\phi \in {\cal H}$.
6. $U_t$ is weakly continuous at every $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\langle \psi| U_t \phi\rangle \to \langle \psi|U_{t_0}\phi\rangle$, as $t\to t_0$, for every pair $\psi,\phi \in {\cal H}$.

If ${\cal H}$ is finite dimensional all topologies boil down to the **uniform one** (the normed topology with norm $||A|| = \sup\{||Ax|| \:|\: x\in {\cal H}\:, \quad  ||x||=1\}$) and all fine distinctions are irrelevant. In turn this topology is the same as the one of $\mathbb{C}^{\dim {\cal H}\times \dim {\cal H}}$ which one naturally uses after having identified operators with matrices referred to  any basis of ${\cal H}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really appreciate it. I think it's a bit too complicated for me, though. I guess that to really understand what I'm asking I should have some knowledge that I lack of at the moment. By the way, is it possible to give a safe rule for differentiating operators (specifically those used in QM) without having to be able to deal with such "technicality"? I ask this also because operator differentiation is something quite common in QM, but from your answer it doesn't look to me that this is something the average physicist knows.

Comment: A general rule: Easy intuitive things always  work when the Hilbert space is finite dimensional. They do not hold in general in the infinite-dimensional case but, usually, they still hold  in suitable domains.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, if I had to differentiate a squared operator, such as $H^2$, with respect to $t$, should I go for $2H+\frac{dH}{dt}$ or for the differentiation of the single elements of the matrix associated to $(H^2)$?

Comment: If everything goes right $d/dt H^2=2 H dH/dt$

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical rigorous framework is given by [Stone's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups). As usual in functional analysis, the limits are to be interpreted in the weak sense. In general, an operator is defined on how it acts on wave functions, in the spirit of distributions.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to edit**

I don't quite understand your confusion. Since $H$ is $t$ independent:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{(tH)^n}{n!} = H^n\frac{d}{dt}\frac{t^n}{n!}=H^n\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$
In particular, $\frac{d}{dt}H^n=0$.

Things could get tricky if $H$ had a time dependence. Note that in this case, you typically are not interested in $e^{-itH}$ but rather the time order exponential of the integral of $H$: $U = \mathcal T e^{-i\int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(s)ds}$.

Now, you don't have trivially $\frac{d}{dt}H^n=0$ due to the time dependence of $H$, and your worries are justified. $\frac{d}{dt}H^2$, there are already some issues in finite dimension. The main problem is that if $H$ and $\frac{dH}{dt}$ do not commute, then the naive result is false.

Intuitively, this is due to the ambiguity of the ordering. You'll need to do things more carefully:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H^2 = H\frac{dH}{dt}+\frac{dH}{dt}H
$$
and you recover the usual formula in the commuting case. Similarly for general power:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} H^N= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}H^n\frac{dH}{dt}H^{N-n-1}
$$

Note that usually, you are not interested in powers of $H$, but rather time ordered powers which form the integral. This actually simplifies the expression of the derivative.

Now when you look at it in infinite dimensions, numerous issues can arise. First off, the sum/product of self-adjoint operators are not necessarily self adjoint due to domain issues. The RHS of the formula may therefore not even make much sense. More generally, the LHS may also be ill defined.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I looked a bit around for Stone's Theorem (and also from the answer by Valter), but unfortunately it's quite complicated for my limited knowledge. I thought (or hoped) there was a simpler theory behind it.

Comment: Yes, for infinite dimensional Hilbert space, there are unfortunately no shortcuts. If you want to look into it, Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* is a good starting point. As Valter Moretti answered, physicists typically extrapolate formulas that are true in finite dimensional Hilbert space and hope for the best.